# Check double value when input only have integer and decimal point part

Tags: java, exception

I have a simple method to check double value input from keyboard like this:

```
private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static double checkInputDouble(String s) {
    while (true)
        try {
            System.out.print(s);
            double result = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine().trim());
            return result;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("> INPUT MUST BE DOUBLE NUMBER...");
        }
}
```

But I want to extend a situation. For example, if your input is 3.14, it will return 3.14 . But if you enter 3. (3 and decimal point only) it return 3.0.

**How to catch that exception and show it to on-screen output?**

Comment: Please add some examples for valid and invalid input,

Comment: It seems like this is not a matter of catching another exception. If you parse `3` as a double the parseDouble function will not throw an exception but parse the number correctly. Most likely you will have to use specific formatting when writing the value to the console. (I can sadly not tell you how as im not familiar with string formatting in java)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than catching the exception and show it on the screen you can read it as String and then check if it ends with ., append it with 0. Like below:

```
private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static double checkInputDouble(String s) {
    while (true)
        try {
            System.out.print(s);
            String dou = sc.nextLine().trim();
            if(dou.endsWith(".")){
               dou = dou + "0";
            }
            double result = Double.parseDouble(dou);
            return result;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("> INPUT MUST BE DOUBLE NUMBER...");
        }
}
```

**Input :** 3.

**Output :** 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a condition to check the last character of the input and throw NumberFormatException if character is "." .

```
private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static double checkInputDouble(String s) {
    while (true)
        try {
            System.out.print(s);
            String nextLine = sc.nextLine().trim();
            if (nextLine.endsWith(".")) {
                throw new NumberFormatException();
            }
            double result = Double.parseDouble(nextLine);
            return result;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("> INPUT MUST BE DOUBLE NUMBER...");
        }
}
```